# Show all data in column

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to show all of the data in the 'status' column of my table but am having troubles. What am I doing wrong:

```
<?php 
$query1 = "SELECT id, status FROM alerts WHERE customerid='".$_SESSION['customerid']."' ORDER BY id LIMIT $start, $limit ";
$result = mysql_query($query1);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['status'] ;
}
?>
```

Comment: any errors coming out?

did you try ini_set('display_errors', "On"); and error_reporting(1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query1 = "SELECT id, `status` FROM alerts WHERE customerid='".$_SESSION['customerid']."' ORDER BY id LIMIT $start, $limit ";

$result = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());    
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))    
{  
  echo $row['status'];
}
```

Also, make sure that:

`$_SESSION['customerid']`, `$start` and `$limit` are not empty. You can test the constructed query with `echo $query1;`

**Note:** Addition of `mysql_error()` in in the `mysql_query` will allow you to see if there is an error in the query.

> I am trying to show all of the data in
>   the 'status' column of my table

If you want to show ***all*** the rows, your query should be:

```
$query1 = "SELECT id, `status` FROM alerts ORDER BY id";
```

But if you want to show for a specific customer, your query should be:

```
$query1 = "SELECT id, `status` FROM alerts WHERE customerid='".$_SESSION['customerid']."' ORDER BY id";
```

Comment: Completely missed the variables $start and $limit. They were both blank Thankyou!